# Recent Windows update broke smartphone connectivity and windows media player

Tags: windows-10, android, device-manager, windows-10-v1511

Seems like my windows 10 updated itself to a new version without telling me first* (my winver says 1511 build 10586.36 - Windows 10 Pro N).

As a result, I lost several program functionalities, including Windows Media Player, and I can't access my Android One Plus 2 device files anymore (the "Android" device icon no longer shows up in the file explorer).

I had a look at the "devices and printer" section of the control panel, it only shows my Android device as a CD-ROM drive icon (OnePlus2 has this kind of partition so we can install drivers from a computer from the phone), And I can't see the "phone" device anymore as I used to before. In the device manager, I still have a ADB Interface installed, but it seems to be a rubbish microsoft one, and not from the driver from Android "ADB Interface" that I had previously installed following [those instructions](http://www.technobuzz.net/oneplus-two-usb-drivers/). This generic device appears as a "Universal Serial Bus devices", whereas the Android driver belongs to the "Android Device" category.

The problem is that **I cannot change the driver type**. "Select from the list" now only shows a couple options with the microsoft drivers. If I try to uninstall it, on the next refresh the device will be reinstalled with that generic non-working driver (FYI, It's known as WinUSB > ADB Device). **The fact that Windows now recognize the device as belonging to the "USB devices" category prevents me from selecting the official Android ADB belonging to the "Android devices" category**.

If I connect as PTP, nothing appears at all.

I believe I could fix my problem if I could force the device to be reinstalled as an Android ADB device, or force it to appear as an "unknown device" so that I would be able to choose its driver type as "Android". An-y idea how I could do that ?

* *I am actually not 100% sure of what happened, but once I opened my PC and I saw the windows screens saying "Hi, we're configuring your PC, blah blah". So I assumed this was indeed because of an update*

EDIT

- Updated to 10586.63
- Reinstalled [Windows Media Pack for Windows N](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3010081) but still no windows media player showing up (and when I try reinstalling the KB it says it's already installed). Note [that some](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/mtp-driver-windows-10.337070/) forum suggests that this could be the cause for my Android device not connecting properly. I do not have the "Portable devices" category in my driver selection list.

Comment: You are missing updates, `10586.36` is out of date, do yourself installed your pending updates.  How do you have Windows Media Player, if you have the version, that is specifically designed not to have it?

Comment: " I am actually not 100% sure of what happened ...." - Yes that is what happen but .36 was installed released weeks ( more then a month ) ago.  So your behind on numerous updates.

Comment: Actually my windows update keeps throwing "error 0x80244018". This is probably what has blocked my updates... I have tried some fixes but to no avail. There doesn't seem to be a lot of info concerning that error.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not know, several days ago everything was going fine. Concerning windows media player, I had probably found a fix some time ago to reinstall windows media player, and I have been using it quite often. But suddenly I can't open files with this program anymore and it seems to have been completely removed from my PC :o. I will try to look for some log info on what exactly happened...

Comment: You will have to repeat that fix, when you updated to `10586.36`, Windows was more or less installed again since I presume you were using 10240.  You need to resolve your update problem before anything else can be fixed though.

Comment: I completed several updates and I am now at `10586.63`. Concerning WMP I remember now, I had installed the Media Feature Pack for Windows 10 N. I redownloaded/installed it again but wmp still doesn't show up :(

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to all those problems [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-n-was-removed-by/f593a2ec-d475-44e3-8eb9-cd3f0cbf69fa?page=2&tm=1453936539299&auth=1#LastReply).

The problem and solution only targets Windows 10 N systems

In a nutshell, the Media Feature Pack from before was rendered useless with 1511 build, and and a newer yet well-hidden version of that pack must be downloaded and installed (KB3099229_x64.msu).

*(Note that is is still possible to reinstall the previous version of this pack, KB3010081, it is very easy to find the links, it will let you do it and say it is installed successfully, but nothing works)*

And the drivers for smartphone connectivity are in that pack, along with WMP.

Comment: +1 just because I should have thought to ask that question.